Extracting values from a bar chart
I have a dataset with horizontal and vertical bar charts. My goal is to read these pictures and obtain data in the form of bar name = bar value. I currently have 2 codes. The first one is cv2 + hough transform to find the pixel value of the bars. The second code is to read the numeric values in this bar graph image with pytesseract and find the largest value. After finding this, I assign the max value to the data with the highest pixel value. In the remaining columns, I make a proportion from the largest column and assign a value. The rest of the work is to somehow read the names of the bars from the image and make the matching.
I delete everything except the bars and count the pixels according to the remaining objects.
Image with just the bar, where I did the pixel count:

Pixel count graph:

Picture where I get the maximum number value in the graph:

Again, I try to get the names of the bars by trying to extract text from the image using pytesseract, but I always get either missing or misread data. I can't move forward because I'm stuck in this part. When I get this part done, there is still the matching part, but of course I explode here because I can't get the names.
Column piksel numbers:, [23068.], [14299.], [8453.], [24727.]
New values: [34, 57, 93, 100]
First Python Code (finding pixels)
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

imagePath = r"C:"
image = cv2.imread(imagePath)

new_width = 800
new_height = 600
resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (new_width, new_height))

gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(resized_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

hist = cv2.calcHist([gray_image], [0], None, [256], [0,256])

# Detect columns using the Hough Transform
edges = cv2.Canny(gray_image, 50, 150)
#lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, threshold=100, minLineLength=100, maxLineGap=10)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges,rho = 1,theta = 1*np.pi/180,threshold = 100,minLineLength = 100,maxLineGap = 50)

if not lines.any():
    print("No columns could be detected in the picture.")
    exit()

mask = np.zeros_like(gray_image)
for line in lines:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
    cv2.line(gray_image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 3)

white_image = cv2.erode(gray_image, np.ones((2, 2)), iterations=8)  # Kernel boyutunu ve iterasyon sayısını resminize göre ayarlayabilirsiniz.

white_image = cv2.dilate(gray_image, np.ones((2, 2)), iterations=8)  # Kernel boyutunu ve iterasyon sayısını resminize göre ayarlayabilirsiniz.

# Calculating the histogram of a bleached image
white_hist = cv2.calcHist([white_image], [0], None, [256], [0,256])

selected_pixels = np.where((white_hist > 300) & (white_hist < 40000))[0]
column_heights = white_hist[selected_pixels]

# Update the histogram and limit it to the maximum threshold
white_hist[white_hist > 30000] = 30000

print("Column piksel numbers:", *column_heights, sep=", ")

en_buyuk_deger = max(column_heights)

# Calculate ratios and assign new values
new_values = []
for deger in column_heights:
    new_value = 100 * (deger / en_buyuk_deger)
    new_values.append(int(new_value))

new_values.sort()
print("New values:", new_values)

cv2.imshow("gray picture",gray_image)
cv2.imshow("white picture",white_image)
#cv2.imshow('Kesilmiş Resim', white_image)

plt.plot(white_hist)
plt.title('Image Histogram ')
plt.xlabel('Pixel Value')
plt.ylabel('Pixel Count')
plt.show()



cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


Second Python Code (for finding max integer value in picture)
import cv2
import pytesseract

def find_largest_number(data):
  largest_number = None

  for line in data.split("\n"):
    for word in line.split():
      try:
        number = int(word)

        if largest_number is None or number > largest_number:
          largest_number = number
      except ValueError:
        pass

  return largest_number

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
imagePath = r"C:"
image = cv2.imread(imagePath)

new_width = 800
new_height = 600
resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (new_width, new_height))

gray = cv2.cvtColor(resized_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, lang='eng',config='--psm 6')
print(data)

largest_integer = find_largest_number(data)
print("Largest Number:", largest_integer)



cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey()

Some dataset examples:






your post is quite extensive and difficult to skim. I also don't see any question marks. please review [ask]
